# Extract a single file from a tar file and put it to another directory

Tags: directory, ksh, tar

I need to extract a single file from a tar file to another directory.

So far I have this:

This one extracts a single file to same directory:

```
tar -xvf filename.tar ./file.txt
```

I tried this but it's not working

```
tar -xvf filename.tar /home/dir ./file.txt
```

or this:

```
tar -xvf filename.tar -C /home/dir ./file.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a wrong argument in your last command. Try the following:

```
tar xvf filename.tar -C other_dir file.txt
```

`./file.txt` should be `file.txt`.

Comment: $ tar xvf ip-10-1-1-254.lykos-apps.2020-11-06.tar -C /home/appuser/backup-L2/tmp2 lykos-email.2020-11-06.0.log
lykos-email.2020-11-06.0.log

--- I tried it and it works, great answer